# TinyMCE and AngularJS - not loading after NgSwitch

Tags: html, angularjs, tinymce

I hope I am clear enough with this request for assistance, as it is hard to explain and I can't post all the code here.  I have downloaded code to enable TinyMCE to be used in a NgRepeat with AngularJS:

```js
angular.module('ui.tinymce', [])
    .value('uiTinymceConfig', {})
    .directive('uiTinymce', ['uiTinymceConfig', function (uiTinymceConfig) {
        uiTinymceConfig = uiTinymceConfig || {};
        var generatedIds = 0;
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ngModel) {
                var expression, options, tinyInstance;
                // generate an ID if not present
                if (!attrs.id) {
                    attrs.$set('id', 'uiTinymce' + generatedIds++);
                }
                options = {
                    // Update model when calling setContent (such as from the source editor popup)
                    setup: function (ed) {
                        ed.on('init', function (args) {
                            ngModel.$render();
                        });
                        // Update model on button click
                        ed.on('ExecCommand', function (e) {
                            ed.save();
                            ngModel.$setViewValue(elm.val());
                            if (!scope.$$phase) {
                                scope.$apply();
                            }
                        });
                        // Update model on keypress
                        ed.on('KeyUp', function (e) {
                            ed.save();
                            ngModel.$setViewValue(elm.val());
                            if (!scope.$$phase) {
                                scope.$apply();
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    mode: 'exact',
                    elements: attrs.id
                };
                if (attrs.uiTinymce) {
                    expression = scope.$eval(attrs.uiTinymce);
                } else {
                    expression = {};
                }
                angular.extend(options, uiTinymceConfig, expression);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    tinymce.init(options);
                });


                ngModel.$render = function () {
                    if (!tinyInstance) {
                        tinyInstance = tinymce.get(attrs.id);
                    }
                    if (tinyInstance) {
                        tinyInstance.setContent(ngModel.$viewValue || '');
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    }]);


var gwApp = angular.module('gwApp', ['ui.tinymce']);
```

I don't really understand this code, but it works fine initially.  My page starts with a list of Posts.  I click on 'Show Reply' for the first post, and using NgSwitch the multiple replies become visible (nested NgRepeat).  I submit a new reply message (the reply text is entered using tinymce) using a RESTful API service and a http call (too much code to post here).  Then after clicking the submit button for the new reply message, the NgSwitch kicks in again unexpectedly to make the replies no longer visible.  When I expand the replies again, the tinymce is just a regular textarea again, and the proper editor is gone.

I know this is not very clear, but I'm hoping someone can make sense of what I've written and can help me solve this problem..

Comment: Correction - I am using ngShow not ngSwitch

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem using `ng-switch` and `ng-show` so i added:

```
scope.$watch('onHidden()',function(){ tinymce.editors = [] });
```

after the `setTimeout` function.

Also replace the

```
ed.on('init',function(args){  ngModel.$render(); });
```

with

```
ed.on('init',function(args){  ed.setContent(ngModel.$viewValue); });
```

and remove the `$render` function.

[This is the link to the working code in JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5fxtpk2k/11/)